# Communication between 2 Beaglebone black using ethernet cable and port

Tags: linux, tcp, network-programming

I am currently working on a project where I am attempting to establish communication between two BeagleBone Black boards using the Ethernet port. One board is set up as the server, and the other as the client.

The server's Ethernet IP address is configured as 169.254.1.1, and it is listening at port 8088. Similarly, the client's Ethernet IP address is set to 169.254.1.2, and it is trying to connect to the server at the same port (8088).

However, I have encountered a challenge that I am seeking assistance with. When I run the server code, everything appears to be functioning normally. However, upon executing the client code, I encounter the message "connect: connection refused." As a result, I am unable to establish communication between the two BeagleBone Black boards.

Strangely, I have noticed that when I run both the server and client programs on the same machine, they communicate successfully without any issues.

I have attached the server.c and client.c programs to this email for your reference. I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance you may have in resolving this communication problem between the BeagleBone Black boards.

If you require any additional information or code snippets, please do not hesitate to ask. Your expertise and assistance are highly valued and will be immensely helpful in overcoming this obstacle.

Thank you in advance for your support.

```
server.c
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<time.h>
char buffer[1024],buffer1[1024];









int main(void)
{
    int stat =2, socket_desc=0,socket_bind,socket_listen,socket_accept,true=1,read_size,send_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
        socklen_t *addrlen;
        time_t t;
    unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    //addrlen=length;


    struct sockaddr bind_sock;

    

    socket_desc=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    perror("socket");

    /*if(connect(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server))<0)
    {
        printf("connect error\n");
    }
    else
        printf("connected\n");

    perror("connect");*/

    setsockopt(socket_desc,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR|            SO_REUSEPORT,&true,sizeof(int));
    perror("setsockopt");
    bind_sock.sa_family=AF_INET;
    strcpy(bind_sock.sa_data,"169.254.1.1");// 127.0.0.1

    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("169.254.1.1");//127.0.0.1
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(8088);//59944

    
        socket_bind=bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
            perror("bind");

    socket_listen=listen(socket_desc,5);
    perror("listen");


    socket_accept=accept(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr*)&client,(socklen_t *)&length);
    perror("accept");
    while(1)
    {
    if(fork()==0)
    {
      
              read(socket_accept,buffer,1024); 
              time(&t);
              printf("client : %s %s\n",buffer,ctime(&t));
        
   

     }

     else
     {
              
           scanf("%[^\n]",buffer1);
           send(socket_accept,buffer1,1024,0);
            wait(&stat);
          

         }


     }

    close(socket_desc);

}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
client.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<time.h>
char buffer[1024],buffer1[1024];


int main(void)
{

    int stat,true=1, socket_desc,socket_bind,socket_listen,socket_accept,read_size,send_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
        socklen_t *addrlen;
        time_t t;
    unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    


    struct sockaddr bind_sock;

    

    socket_desc=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    perror("socket");
    
    setsockopt(socket_desc,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR|          SO_REUSEPORT,&true,sizeof(int));
    perror("setsockopt");
    
    bind_sock.sa_family=AF_INET;
    strcpy(bind_sock.sa_data,"169.254.1.2");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("169.254.1.2");//127.0.0.1
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(49508);//59944

    

    
        socket_bind=connect(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
            perror("connect");

   
            while(1)
            {
    if(fork()==0)
    {
     
        gets(buffer1);
        send(socket_desc,buffer1,1024,0);

    }

     else
     {
         
           
           read_size=read(socket_desc,buffer,1024);
               time(&t);           
               printf("server : %s %s\n",buffer,ctime(&t));
               wait(&stat);
            


     }

            }

    close(socket_desc);

}
```

Best regards,
Mohan T

Comment: You should check return values for error before printing error messages. Why `strcpy(bind_sock.sa_data,"169.254.1.1")`?  You bind() server to port 8088 but connect client to 49508. `tcpdump` is your best friend in debugging such things.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you've copy and pasted from server.c to client.c without carefully checking your values.  As dimich points out in a comment, you aren't using the same port on the client and server.  But also, you are trying to connect to your own IP address.

On the client I think you want:

```
server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("169.254.1.1");
server.sin_port=htons(8088);
```

You are declaring `bind_sock` and both `server` and `client` variables in client.c which might be confusing you.  I suspect you really wanted to use the client variable on the client.

I would recommend turning on all warnings in your compiler, probably with something like `-Wall -Werror` if you're using gcc.  Then make sure it compiles cleanly without any issues.

Good luck.

Comment: Hello    Thank you so much for your suggestion the same code is working after changing server address in client program